# How can I print a new line in Colab?

Tags: python, printing, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab and want to break up a sentence into two lines. I have tried \n and \r, but they do not work.

```
test = "This is the first line. \r\n This is the second line"
test
```

This is a link to the code

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11FhjbT2VvCepdFKSCTVQjYtQfnSxsrTH?usp=sharing

Comment: just `print(test)`

Comment: Oh that worked, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML tags, so you can use `<br>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32354599)

Comment: How come this is not an answer?! this is an answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

TYZ gave me the answer.
print(test) instead of just test.